# Settlers of catan number on tiles in php

Tags: php, image, random, overlay

I've started looking into writing a Settlers of catan clone.
I would like this to be handled in php (+mysql) as much as possible since the idea is a turned based game for multiple players that just join with their web broser.

I've created the game map, except for the numbers on the tiles that decides if you get a resource or not when rolling the dice.

The best way, I think, would be to at game start pick a tile and assign it a random value from the database (each time reducing the number of options as we pcik new ones). That value points to an image that overlays the tile. After that store the coordinates for the tile and the value in the database for future reference.
Then repeat for the next tile.

Does this makes sence? How would any of you do it?
As I said I'm happy to keep it in php as much as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better would be to generate the set of all numbers that will go on the board, then shuffle that set, and then assign each tile the next number in the set.

That way, you don't have to keep looking up what numbers are left in the set, you can just go through them one by one.

You can use [`shuffle()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) to do the randomization of the order, once you've created the array of numbers. If you're just going with the basic Catan rules, the set of possible numbers will always be the same, so you can just hard-code that.